# CGAL draw function is giving 'CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined' error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, cgal, point-clouds

I am trying to generate mesh and 3D object from point cloud. I have searched lots of libraries and I decided to use CGAL. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWAuP6FN0d4) youtube tutorial. Due to the fact that I want to see the objects, I need to use Qt5 library (as mentioned [here](https://doc.cgal.org/4.13/Triangulation_2/index.html#Triangulation2Draw)) and I downloaded it. And it worked as in tutorial.

Libraries and applications I've used

- CMake 3.15.3
- CGAL-4.13.1
- Qt 5.13.0
- Boost 1_71_0

The problem is that when I call the `CGAL::draw()` function it gives me this error

> Impossible to draw because CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined.

When I have searched for it, I have generally found

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER
>   LIBS+=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER

`.pro` file solution (I don't have .pro file) and [this](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/How-to-draw-a-Triangulation-with-Qt-td4663779.html)

I couldn't handle with them. 
Is there a windows visual studio solution?
How do we define `CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER`?
Do I need to import some Qt5 libs?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
My problem was that I was following the video. And in the video, the guy didn't build the source with cmake, he added libraries etc with manually.

When I build the source code with cmake, it works.
There is a very simple tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYmgbqGfv-8).

Comment: Do you use cmake ?

Comment: Yes I use cmake @gdamiand

Comment: if there is a way easier, I want to hear? @gdamiand

Comment: I think cmake is the simplest way. Have a look at the CMakeLists.txt in Triangulation_3 example https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Triangulation_3/examples/Triangulation_3/CMakeLists.txt; you need (1) to use cgal with QT5; (2) to define CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER using add_definitions; (3) to link your program with CGAL_Qt5 using target_link_libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With cmake, you need to do the following to use CGAL basic viewers:

1) use cgal with QT5

find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt5)

2) define CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER

add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER)

3) link your program with CGAL_Qt5

target_link_libraries(myexe PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Qt5)

Have a look to the different examples in CGAL that uses basic viewer, for example  [draw_triangulation_3.cpp](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Triangulation_3/examples/Triangulation_3/draw_triangulation_3.cpp) and its [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Triangulation_3/examples/Triangulation_3/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: It works, my problem was that I was following the video. And in the video, the guy didn't build the source with cmake, he added libraries etc with manually. Thats why cmake solutions meant nothing for me. Thank you!