# Error CGAL draw function in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, cgal

I have tried to compile CGAL with Visual Studio, unfortunately I am getting every time an error **CGAL::draw()**.
Over the Link below, I have found a solution, but I don't know where and what I need to type in Visual Studio to link my QT-Basic-Viewer and the target_link to compile with CGAL and Visual Studio.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this issue.

[CGAL draw function is giving 'CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined' error in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892242/cgal-draw-function-is-giving-cgal-use-basic-viewer-is-not-defined-error-in-vis)

This is my Cmake Text file:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_cmake_script
# This is the CMake script for compiling a CGAL application.


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.2)
project( Surface_mesh_Examples )


if(POLICY CMP0053)
  # Only set CMP0053 to OLD with CMake<3.10, otherwise there is a warning.
  if(NOT POLICY CMP0070)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)
  else()
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 NEW)
  endif()
endif()
if(POLICY CMP0071)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0071 NEW)
endif()

find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt5)

if(CGAL_Qt5_FOUND)
  add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
endif()

if ( CGAL_FOUND )

  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_derivation.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_join.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_aabbtree.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_bgl.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_circulators.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_do_intersect.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_iterators.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_kruskal.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_memory.cpp" )
  create_single_source_cgal_program( "sm_properties.cpp" )

  create_single_source_cgal_program("draw_surface_mesh.cpp")
  create_single_source_cgal_program("sm_draw_small_faces.cpp")
  create_single_source_cgal_program("check_orientation.cpp")
  if(CGAL_Qt5_FOUND )
    target_link_libraries(draw_surface_mesh PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Qt5)
    target_link_libraries(sm_draw_small_faces PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Qt5)
  endif()

else()

    message(STATUS "This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")

endif()
```

And the List of the Installed in CMake, so why do I get an error on the draw function in Visual Studio?

[image]

I now have a check mark in Cmake for the Draw function, but unfortunately I still get the same error in Visual Studio. What exactly can I do to fix the errors?

[image]

Unfortunatly i have a new Problem now, Visual Studio could not find the Data it says the System could not found the Data(see below). What can i do to correct the error, which settings do i have to make ? 
[image]

Comment: Please show the full error message and a [mre] with your code

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Unfortunately I only get this error, draw is underlined red in Visual Studio

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have add the whole Cmake text and the installation guide, if that can help you understand the exact problem. I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Probably CGAL_Qt5 is not configured, probably because it misses some dependencies. Run cmake on CGAL root, and read all the log messages; it will give you the list of missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `cgal[qt]` in vcpkg and not only `cgal`, or else you will be missing some dependencies for the graphical examples. 
Please read [this page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html) for all details on how to use CGAL from vcpkg.